# Missing dependency when trying to update

Tags: linux

Fedora 12 
2.6.32.9-67.fc12.i686

I have tried doing the recommended as its saids at the bottom. However, that didn't work. So I have to yum upgrade --skip-broken

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Many thanks

```
nss-3.12.6-1.2.fc12.i686 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: nspr >= 4.8.4 is needed by package nss-3.12.6-1.2.fc12.i686 (updates)
nss-3.12.6-1.2.fc12.i686 from updates has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: nss-util = 3.12.6 is needed by package nss-3.12.6-1.2.fc12.i686 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: nspr >= 4.8.4 is needed by package nss-3.12.6-1.2.fc12.i686 (updates)
Error: Missing Dependency: nss-util = 3.12.6 is needed by package nss-3.12.6-1.2.fc12.i686 (updates)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nss` update depends on an `nspr` update that hasn't made it into the `updates` repository yet. You can either enable the `updates-testing` repository (check the yum help for how to do this) or just wait until the `nspr` update is pushed to the `updates` repository.

Also, a good place to look when you have this sort of issue is the [Fedora Forums](http://fedoraforum.org/). In particular, this case is covered here: http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=242125